Create an Azure Container Registry with Customer Managed Encryption Keys in Bicep
I am attempting to create an Azure Container Registry using Bicep. This registry must use Customer Managed Encryption keys. The ACR fails to get created with the encryption enabled.
The keyvault, identity, role assignments, and even the key get created, but it fails to create the Container Registry:
Invalid KeyId '/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/mykeyvaultname/keys/key-mycontainerregistry' specified in encryption property for registry 'mycontainerregistry'
(Code: IdentitiesClientError)
I've double checked that all the params related to the identity that are passed into the ACR module match the identity defined in Azure (Resource ID and Client ID).
This creates the KeyVault
param azureRegion string
param tenantId string
var keyVaultName = 'mykeyvaultname'

@description('Set up a key vault')
resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-07-01' = {
  name: keyVaultName
  location: azureRegion
  tags:{
    client: 'qPlatform'
    dataclassification: 'Confidential'
    businesscriticality: 'Mission-critical'
    environment: environment
  }
  properties: {
    tenantId: tenantId
    sku: {
      family: 'A'
      name: 'premium'
    }
    enabledForDiskEncryption: true
    enabledForTemplateDeployment: true
    enabledForDeployment: true
    enablePurgeProtection: true
    enableSoftDelete: true
    enableRbacAuthorization: true
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    softDeleteRetentionInDays: 90
  }
}

output keyVaultName string = keyVault.name
output keyVaultId string = keyVault.id

We have a user assigned identity that we assign the keyvault permissions to
param containerRegistryManagedIdentityName string
param keyVaultName string

@description('Get the existing KeyVault reference')
resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2019-09-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultName
}

@description('This is the built-in Key Vault Crypto User User role.')
resource keyVaultCryptoUserRoleRoleDefinition 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions@2018-01-01-preview' existing = {
  scope: subscription()
  name: '12338af0-0e69-4776-bea7-57ae8d297424'
}

@description('Get the existing managed identity for the container registry')
resource containerRegistryManagedIdentity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2018-11-30' existing = {
  name: containerRegistryManagedIdentityName
  scope: resourceGroup()
}

@description('Grant the container registry identity with key vault crypto user role permissions over the key vault.')
resource storageKeyVaultCryptoUserRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  scope: keyVault
  name: guid(keyVault.id, containerRegistryManagedIdentity.id, keyVaultCryptoUserRoleRoleDefinition.id)
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: keyVaultCryptoUserRoleRoleDefinition.id
    principalId: containerRegistryManagedIdentity.properties.principalId
  }
}

This is the container definition where we create the encryption key on the vault and use the user assigned identity
param environment string
param azureRegion string
param sku string = 'Premium'
param keyVaultName string
param identityClientId string
param identityId string

var name = 'mycontainerregistry'

resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2021-10-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultName
}

var keyName = 'key-${name}'

resource key 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys@2019-09-01' = {
  name: keyName
  parent: keyVault
  properties: {
    attributes: {
      enabled: true
    }
    keySize: 2048
    kty: 'RSA'
  }
}

resource acr 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries@2023-01-01-preview' = {
  name: name
  location: azureRegion
  tags:{
    client: 'qPlatform'
    dataclassification: 'Confidential'
    businesscriticality: 'High'
    environment: environment
  }
  sku: {
    name: sku
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${identityId}':{}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    adminUserEnabled: true
    encryption: {
      keyVaultProperties: {
        identity: identityClientId
        keyIdentifier: key.id
      }
      status: 'enabled'
    }
  }
}



keyIdentifier: key.id is not correctly coded here. It should be Key vault uri to access the encryption key. But your code provided is a keyvault resourceId, something like /subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx-test-once-rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/wbtestkeyvault2/keys/wbkey
It is not a uri, it should have the pattern https://xxxx.vault.azure.net/
resource acr 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries@2023-01-01-preview' = {
  name: name
  location: azureRegion
  sku: {
    name: sku
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${identityId}':{}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    adminUserEnabled: true
    encryption: {
      keyVaultProperties: {
        identity: identityClientId
        keyIdentifier: uri('https://${keyVaultName}${environment().suffixes.keyvaultDns}', '/')
      }
      status: 'enabled'
    }
  }
}


Thank you for the answer @wenbo. I found a URI property on the key which did the trick. 'keyVaultProperties: {
identity: identityClientId
keyIdentifier: key.properties.keyUri
}'

That's pretty better than my code, -_-
